# Error installing emacs-redo+ with nix package manager

Tags: emacs, nix

Running `nix-env -i emacs-redo+` gives me an error.

```
inaimathi@self:~$ nix-env -i emacs-redo+
error: selector ‘emacs-redo+’ matches no derivations
inaimathi@self:~$
```

But the package both seems to exist, and is visible.

```
inaimathi@self:~$ nix-env -qa | grep emacs-redo
emacs-redo+-20131117.551
inaimathi@self:~$
```

Giving the exact package name, and escaping the `+` gives me the same error.

```
inaimathi@self:~$ nix-env -i emacs-redo+-20131117.551
error: selector ‘emacs-redo+-20131117.551’ matches no derivations
inaimathi@self:~$ nix-env -i emacs-redo\+
error: selector ‘emacs-redo+’ matches no derivations
inaimathi@self:~$ nix-env -i emacs-redo\+-20131117.551
error: selector ‘emacs-redo+-20131117.551’ matches no derivations
inaimathi@self:~$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you've made the command `nix-env -qa | grep emacs-redo` succeed, but my attempts to locate the package that way all show nothing:

```
$ git checkout -q master && git log -1 --oneline 
310aadc Merge pull request #12557 from ryanartecona/nixos-manual-custom-options
$ nix-env -qa | grep -i redo
exit code: 1

$ git checkout -q release-15.09 && git log -1 --oneline 
5a4e183 linux: patch CVE-2016-0728 (close #12492)
$ nix-env -qa | grep -i redo
exit code: 1

$ git checkout -q release-14.12 && git log -1 --oneline 
9d6ba7d keepassx: 0.4.3 -> 0.4.4
$ nix-env -qa | grep -i redo
haskell-heredoc-ghc7.8.3-0.2.0.0-profiling-shared
haskell-heredoc-ghc7.8.3-0.2.0.0-shared
haskell-heredoc-ghc7.8.3-0.2.0.0-shared
```

As far as I can tell, there is no `emacs-redo`, hence it's not surprising that `nix-env -i` won't work for that package.

However, if you're following the `master` branch of the Nixpkgs git repository (a.k.a. the `unstable` channel), then you'll find that package in the `emacsPackagesNg` package set as follows:

```
$ nix-env -qaP -A emacsPackagesNg | grep -i redo
emacsPackagesNg.redo-plus    emacs-redo-plus-20131117.551
```

If you want to use that, then you may have to convert your Emacs installation to that new package set entirely -- I don't believe that you easily mix packages from the old and the new Emacs package set.

Anyhow, `emacsPackagesNg` is work-in-progress and it may not be completely reliable yet, although https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/11503 suggests that people *do* use it successfully already.

Comment: After doing a `nix-channel --update`, I can no longer see that package. Older version or something, I guess? Accepting this even though it doesn't exactly solve my problem; it's a good explanation.